# Tracking displays of iframe component in Google Analytics

Tags: iframe, widget, google-analytics, cross-site

Site A gives their affiliates an interactive component (traffic map based on Google Maps), which they in turn put on their sites (Site B) in an iframe. The component is dynamic, doesn't change the URL of parent site, and has an id for each affiliate site.

What I would like to do is track the displays of the component. (Price of using Google Maps for the component depends on number of views).

At the moment the component is in `<iframe src="http://SiteA.com/q?cp=43.520,18.910,10&cm=1"></iframe>`.

I have looked at the other topics but didn't found a solution to that problem. I would really appreciate any help, I had no experience with cross-site tracking yet.

Comment: What is `q?cp=43.520,18.910,10&cm=1`?  GPS coordinates?

Comment: Yeah, those were coordinates for embedded map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You as siteA owner want to count number of displays of iframe on other sites, correct?

The basic way to do it is logs analysis — every time your server returns page http://SiteA.com/q?cp=43.520,18.910,10&cm=1 or similar it adds an entry to your server's log files. The can be count when. There is a number of solutions for analyzing log data. Some of them opensource and free, other are paid services. For exmaple: http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

There is other ways to count it, but it's probably easiest way of all.